# how to draw a floor map in android?

Tags: android, maps, floor

I need to draw a floor map in my android application which will be later used to navigate the user and much more.
I need some advise on how i can programmatically draw a floor plan in my application? is the graphic class is the only way ?

Answer (score -1):

Of course I cannot provide you with the code to do that, but you can define a custom view :

```
public class FloorView extends View {

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // Use the canvas to draw to floor map.
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please check this [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N25MxHZ9dDE) and give me clue or guide me or help me to find tutorials. I'm trying to place some objects on real world coordinates through Android camera when I click.